# Why the frame remain orthonormal under the flow?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

Why the frame will remain orthonormal under flow ?

At the beginning ($t=0$),if we choice a good frame that $g_{ij}=\delta_{ij}$,it is obvious that ${F_a}$ is orthonormal. But under the flow , $F_a(t)$ has changed, so, the pullback metric will be a constant about $t$, so,seemly  there is not  condition keep the frame still be orthonormal.

The below picture is from 185th page of  [paper](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ajm/1154098947).Sorry for my laze.
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition we want to preserve is $h_{ab} = g(F_a, F_b) = \delta_{ab}$. Since this is true at the initial time it suffices to show $\partial_t h_{ab} = 0$. The given evolution equation for $F$ is exactly what's needed for this: applying the product rule and the Ricci flow equation we get $$\partial_t h_{ab} = -2 R_{ij} F_a^i F_b^j + 2 g_{ij} g^{il}R_{lk} F^k_a F^j_b = 0.$$

Comment: Although there is not Ricci flow in the picture ,but I think it just be missed.

Comment: Whether the $g_{ij}g^{il}=\delta_{jl}$ ? We can do that at the $t=0$ by choice a good frame. but under the Ricci flow ,I can't see the $g_{ij}(t)g^{il}(t)=\delta_{jl}$ for $t\neq 0$

Comment: @lanse2pty: this is the definition of the inverse metric $g^{il}$!

Comment: I feel bad, I'm so stupid..